# Long return type hint and pep8

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pep8

I have a function that raises an `E501 line too long (86 > 79 characters)` warning when running `pycodestyle`.

```
def my_function(arg1: list = None) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.Dataframe]:
    # do stuff
    return df1, df2, df3
```

What is the best solution for formatting long return type hints (preferably without changing the format of the arguments? e.g.

```
def my_function(arg1: list = None) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame,
                                            pd.DataFrame,
                                            pd.Dataframe]:
```

Comment: This is a great question, and one I've been wondering myself. I feel like this is something that should be addressed by the python language development team, or whoever it is that writes PEPs on python style

Answer (score 4):

You could try `\`:

```
def my_function(arg1: list = None)\
        -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.Dataframe]:
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you use [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/). This will automatically format the code for you. Keep it mind to have same line lengths for both black and pycodestyle

Comment: Maybe you could share what the solution from a package like black would be? I know that there are packages to automate pep8, I was more interested in finding out what was the best/most pythonic format in this case as there are multiple possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases).

```
type DataFrames = Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.Dataframe]

def my_function(arg1: list = None) -> DataFrames:
    # do stuff
    return df1, df2, df3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) would produce:

```py
def my_function(
    arg1: list = None,
) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.Dataframe]:
    # do stuff
    return df1, df2, df3
```

I obtained this output by pasting your input into a file `long_typehint.py` and running the following command:

```bash
$ black --line-length 79 long_typehint.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the closing parenthesis and the return type hint on the next line:

```py
def my_function(arg1: list = None
    ) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    # do stuff
    return df1, df2, df3
```